# How to create a boundary for fixed elements using only one container?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, css-transforms

Here's a [quote](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#containing-block-for-all-descendants) from W3C on how `transform` establishes a new containing block:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value
> other than none for the transform property also causes the element to
> establish a containing block for all descendants. Its padding box will
> be used to layout for all of its absolute-position descendants,
> fixed-position descendants, and descendant fixed background
> attachments.

And here's their example code:

```html
<style>
  #container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px dashed black;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  
  #bloat {
    height: 1000px;
  }
  
  #child {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background: green;
  }
</style>

<div id="container" style="transform:translateX(5px);">
  <div id="bloat"></div>
  <div id="child" style="position:fixed;"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the W3C example doesn't work as expected in Firefox. The green `div` doesn't stay fixed when I scroll — try running the snippet yourself.

My own example has exactly the same problem (the red divs don't stay fixed when I scroll):

```css
.inner-container {
  width: 72vw;
  height: 72vh;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.content {
  height: 88rem;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1%, #e2e2e2 1%, #e2e2e2 3%);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-container">
  <div class="fixed-top"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I don't get it. According to the spec, descendants with `position: fixed` should **not** move if their parent has a `transform` applied, but they do! What gives?

The weird thing is that I can make it work by adding a second container and applying the transform to that instead (now my red divs don't move when I scroll, which is what I want):

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 72vw;
  height: 72vh;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.content {
  height: 88rem;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1%, #e2e2e2 1%, #e2e2e2 3%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="fixed-top"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="fixed-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I have no idea why I need to use **two** containers to make this work. According to the spec I should just be able to apply a `transform` to the first container, which is *so* much cleaner. Is this actually possible with one container? I don't have time to learn Kubernetes at the moment.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tskpp/pen/zYNLaYW) if you want to play with it.

Comment: The duplicate question that was linked to the last time tells you that fixed-positioned elements don't stay "fixed" **because** their containing block is established by an element with a transform, but I understand if this explanation is inadequate. Frankly, not even experts fully understand why they behave this way. But the css-position-3 spec does say that fixed-positioned elements stay "fixed" *only* when their containing block is established by the viewport. One of the lower answers to the linked question mentions position: sticky as a workaround, the same that ssbrear has mentioned below.

Comment: Having said that, 1) please don't delete and repost questions right away next time - give others some time to address your post-closure concerns 2) I also wanted to let you know that I appreciate the Kubernetes joke.

Comment: @BoltClock The duplicate explains **why** fixed-position elements don't stay fixed: "because the transform creates a new local coordinate system". No prob, I understand the cause and effect. What I want to know is the simplest way to invoke it. W3C claim creating a new local coordinate system (containing block) is as easy as adding a transform to the **parent** container of whatever it is you want to affect — but in practice I had to add it to a **grandparent** container, which feels indirect. My question is whether this extra container is required. The term "viewport" could be implicated.

Comment: @BoltClock It's nuanced, I get it, but I feel there's enough of a unique query here to distinguish my question from the supposed duplicate, no? I take full responsibility for poorly articulating it. Thanks for the tips, understood :)

Answer (score 0):

Use position: sticky

There is a fantastic demo at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
.inner-container {
  width: 72vw;
  height: 72vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: sticky;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.content {
  height: 88rem;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, #fff, #fff 1%, #e2e2e2 1%, #e2e2e2 3%);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-container">
  <div class="fixed-top"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that `.fixed-bottom` only stays in position while there's enough content to push it down. If you shrink the height of `.content` you'll see `.fixed-bottom` no longer sticks to the bottom of the container. This is not truly fixed behaviour, and it won't work for a dynamic use-case. Much appreciated suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, I just tested your claim with a much smaller content height and I can confirm this breaks. Thanks for pointing that out!